# Resetting route via cmd

Tags: windows, routing

I have recently encountered problems on Windows 8 with my VPN connection messing us my route settings, and I'm wondering if it is possile to reset the setting to a working state by using `route`, namely reading from the a file `foo.txt` generated by `route print > foo.txt` and then resetting whatever state the the IPv4 Route Table is to be the same as in `foo.txt`. Some of the gateway in the route table is listed as "on-link" instead of ip address.